# How can I tell why a process is waiting?

Tags: process, osx

I'm trying to run a command on OSX Mavericks and it seems to be hanging. I found out that `Control + T` is a Unix command to show the status of a foreground job. Pressing it several times over the course of **several minutes** gives me:

```
$ bin/rake                                                                                
load: 3.68  cmd: ruby 55761 waiting 0.12u 0.02s
load: 3.47  cmd: ruby 55761 waiting 0.12u 0.02s
load: 3.47  cmd: ruby 55761 waiting 0.12u 0.02s
load: 3.09  cmd: ruby 55761 waiting 0.12u 0.02s
load: 2.41  cmd: ruby 55761 waiting 0.12u 0.02s
load: 4.38  cmd: ruby 55761 waiting 0.12u 0.02s
```

I understand this to mean that the status is "waiting", it has spent .12 seconds of user time and only 0.02 seconds of CPU time executing.

I want to find out why it's stuck waiting. **How can I determine why a process is waiting**?

Comment: In this case, I was able to press `Control + C` to interrupt the process, and a stack trace showed me it was trying to read from a socket which presumably was never written to. But I'm still curious if there are other ways to determine this.

Comment: If you do something like `ps -u`, that will show the command that coordinates to each `PID`

Answer (score 1):

Run [`dtruss`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/DOCUMENTATION/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/dtruss.1m.html) to see what system calls a process is making:

```
dtruss -p55761
```

This will tell you what system call the process with PID 55761 is currently engaged in. If that system call accesses some file descriptor, [`lsof`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/DOCUMENTATION/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/lsof.8.html) will tell you what file is open there.

```
lsof -p55761
```

If the file is a pipe or socket, I don't know how to find what if anything is on the other side.